# How do cults indoctrinate people?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, conditioning

You hear stories about cults and the like brainwashing people all the time. How do they psychologically break people down so that they'll join up?

Comment: Questions here generally [require evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277) and enough context to provide an adequate answer for what you need to know.  What have you read on the subject?  There are many different ideas on what constitutes a cult.  What is your definition for the purpose of this question? Different cults use different techniques.  Are you referring to any specific cult?

Comment: Too long to answer here; read https://aeon.co/essays/how-cult-leaders-brainwash-followers-for-total-control for instance.

Comment: Or https://edition.cnn.com/2018/02/13/health/brainwashing-mind-control-patty-hearst/index.html for a more balanced view.